# Invalid Argument: id for 'var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key")); '

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks in advance every one, I created a new project for a Google Spreadsheet, and copied code to a script file of the new project from a previous project code file that runs well in the old project. I just changed the functions names. But when I tried to run the new script file. I get the following error.

`"Invalid argument: id (line 38, file "Code1") Dismiss"`.

Code:

```
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 

function doGet(e) { 
   return addUser4(e.parameter['userIDG'],e.parameter['userNameG']) } 

 function addUser4( userIDG, userNameG) { 
 ///following is line 38, the error 
 //code line, it works in the old project script file 
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key")); }
```

Comment: `getScriptProperties()` gives you properties of *current* script only, so for new script it will return empty string for `.getProperty("key")` and that's why it says `Invalid argument: id`. You need to put there some value first

Comment: Thank you very much, Kos, what value is it? How can I put the value there? Thanks

Comment: `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('key', 'SPREADSHEET_ID')`

Comment: Thanks, solved. The current script propertiy should store the key of the spreadsheet used. Can find the key from previous project and then set in the new project using :Script properties can also be saved via the script editor user interface by going to File > Project properties and selecting the Project properties tab. User properties and document properties cannot be set or viewed in the user interface.